# jquery created data-* sometimes not parsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my HTML i have standard list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

then i add some data-* attribute to `li` tag using jquery.

```
$('li:nth-child(1)').attr('data-token', 'xxxxxxx');
$('li:nth-child(2)').attr('data-token', 'zzzzzzz');
```

when i inspect the `li` tag, it's show the `data-token` with its value, but when i do this with jQuery

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data());
});
```

sometimes, some `li`s tag doesn't have data-token. what is causing this problem?

Comment: ($(this).data(data-token)); you forget data-token

Comment: Try to added using `data()` like `$('li:nth-child(1)').data('token', 'xxxxxxx');`

Comment: It's best not to mix use of `.attr()` and `.data()`. jQuery caches the data attribute the first time you call `.data()`, and changing the attribute after that has no effect on it.

Comment: Your code works just fine. What do you expect? Your code only sets up the "data-token" attribute on the 1st and 2nd `<li>` elements on the page. Any elements after that will have no "data-token" attribute.

Comment: As @Barmar mentioned do not mix `.attr()` && `.data()` replace `$('li:nth-child(1)').attr('data-token', 'xxxxxxx');` with `$('li:nth-child(1)').data('token', 'xxxxxxx');` use `jQuery API` make full use of it.

Comment: @barmar: exactly, when i set `data-token` for second time, it's still return old values. so, better to use `.data()` to set the value?

Comment: Setting `data-` attributes like that is really a completely wrong way of doing things, in any case. Yes, use the `.data()` API if what you want is to keep property sets per DOM node.

Answer (score 1):

`.data()` and `.data(key)` return the value only if stored using the method `.data(key, value)` *and* if it was already present in the DOM as it is in your case.

You're just not specifying, *which* `data-*` attribute you're wanting.

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('token'));
});
```

Comment: Well `.data()` with no argument should return an object with *all* the properties.

Comment: The `.data()` method *will* fetch values from element attributes, and it works perfectly with the code as posted in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens if you call the the `data()` method once then you set the data-* attributes that time it will not sync the values from the data attributes.

So always use the data api to set the values

```
$('li:nth-child(1)').data('token', 'xxxxxxx');
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y5p8stge/4/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y5p8stge/3/)

Comment: The code as written in the OP works just fine. It only adds a `data-token` attribute to the first two `<li>` elements on the page, and `.data()` will correctly fetch the values when it's called after that is done.

Comment: @Pointy The real code is probably more complicated.

Comment: @Pointy yes... it works fine if the order of statements are as given - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y5p8stge/1/ - but when OP says `sometimes, some lis tag doesn't have data-token. what is causing this problem` I think OP is saying `data()` is returning an empty object even though the element have the `data-*` attribute

Comment: @Pointy See his comment where he says "when I set `data-token` for a second time".

Comment: Yes, maybe. It's really not very clear what the OP is talking about :/

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is the OPs problem too.